# Disable URL's for nested levels in structure but keep URL's for the 2 top levels

Tags: url, structure, entries-field, craft4

I have some products with categories that go 4 and sometimes 5 levels deep.
The site will have an overview page for the first 2 levels.
For example: `my-website.com/category/subcategory`

I have created a section called Product categories which has URL's enabled and links to a template.
Can I prevent the deeper levels from having their own URL?

I thought about just returning a 404 inside the template when the level is higher than 2 but the sitemap will still include all these useless URL's.

Another option would be to create the main categories structure with max 2 levels and create another structure for the deeper levels which could be linked to each other.
That way a product section would have a Category (first 2 levels) and a Type (deeper levels) field. The only problem here is that I don't want the Type field to contain all possible values. I want it to be filtered based on the chosen category.

Is one of these options possible?

Comment: Don't compromise your content model for the sake of a sitemap. If you really care that much about sitemaps (I don't believe you should), then amend your sitemap template to not output your level 3+ entries, and 301-redirect them to their parent.